# Resume from TinCan (without LMS)

Tags: tin-can-api, articulate-storyline, xapi

I am trying to use the storyline resume option on my system.

I have my own system to process the storyline parameters, and it works properly.

To launch the storyline presentation I send this URL -

```
"url_to_course?registration='...my_registration'&endpoint='//...my_endpoint'"
```

Now I want to use the resume option, so I saved the data from `"state?method=PUT"` , which looks like this -

```
"Authorization=undefined&Content-Type=application%2Fjson&X-Experience-API-Version=1.0.0&_=0.7401830187747183&resume=true&data=22146070ji1001111a0101101111y101%5E1%5En5r0CkdBPnMj.67JTy4eKzfZ1%5E1%5E002000&activityId=http%3A%2F%2F5wBd0mfmVGO_course_id&agent=%7B%7D&stateId=resume&registration=a30e5748-a544-5ba3-ab3d-0471936e98d3&content=%7B%22data%22%3A%2222146070ji1001111a0101101111y101%5E1%5En5r0CkdBPnMj.67JTy4eKzfZ1%5E1%5E002000%22%7D"
```

So I have the `content` data (suspend data.), which I understood that contains the slide information, and I want to send it on the next login.

What is the exact parameter that I need to send to storyline to active the resume option?

I have tried to send in the url something like this -

```
url_to_course?registration='...my_registration'&endpoint='//...my_endpoint'&content='2o2o405060e07080d090f0a0b0c0~281~2411001114Y010110111101211013110141101012011120121201013011130101401114x300Y1501110101010000000000000000000000000000000010'"
```

The last parameter is the suspent data that I saved, but it always goes to the first slide?

Answer (score 1):

The `state` resource is a Document resource in xAPI and is used by activity providers (like Storyline content) to store arbitrary data inside of an LRS. The storyline content will then try to retrieve that information from the LRS during the launch initialization process, this means that your LRS has to store the data provided during the `POST` request (the `state?method=PUT` which is special syntax that should act like a `PUT`) so that it may then be retrieved during a `GET` request to the same resource. The Storyline content is ignoring your additional parameter as one that it doesn't expect. Once you have both methods of the State resource implemented the Storyline content should work without adjustment to the launch process.

See https://xapi.com/blog/deep-dive-document/ for more about the Document resources, and https://xapi.com/blog/deep-dive-state-activity/ for more specifically about State.